# Does divorce occur if the husband is mentally ill by birth?

Tags: nikah, talaq, husband

If a husband who has a 40+ age, acts like a 5,6 year old child (due to brain trauma) and says the words "talaq" more than twice (for no particular reason) and just small fights occuring between him and his wife (due to his extreme unacceptable childish behaviour and requests that are just off limits), does the talaq actually happen? His brain literally works like a child. He prays and fasts (because he was told to do so since his childhood) but he just doesn't live like an adult. He didn't even know the meaning of this word untill he saw movies and films etc that had this type of stuff in them. Outside of his house, he treats people well and doesn't really seem like a complete mentall person but just a person who is very innocent. But at home, he tries to be dominant and forcefully make his wife and other people do what he tells them because he says I'm the "husband" or I'm an "adult", but obviously no one accepts this behaviour. When he gets treated like a child, he gets hyper and says the word talaq. If we compare him to a child, a child can say anything they hear and he is like that by birth so does the divorce occur? 
We really try to put up with him and we would even accept his childish behaviour but only if he wouldn't go off limits and try to prove that he is an adult. He gets treated very well by his wife, but she fights back and tries to stop him from doing wrong things or being annoying.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.stackexchange. For furtehrninformation refer to the [help] and take our [tour].

Comment: This seems to be asking for a verdict in special circumstances, and we are not a fatwa site. عقل is a condition for validity of divorce, but whether or not the person in this case is qualified needs to be investigated and established.